# Помогите решить задачу, вывод цветов телефонов в зависимости от выбранной модели

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть линейка телефонов iPhone, известно что у различных моделей различные цвета корпуса, как мне например зная, что пользователь выбрал телефон iPhone 5s отобразить только div блоки с цветами gray silver gold? Да это можно организовать через:

```
 if (модель телефона==5s) { 
  скрыть все цвета
  показать gray
  показать silver
  показать gold
} else if {
  и тд
}
```

Но хотелось бы более логичное решение, может есть идеи? При клике на модель телефона берется номер модели из соответствующего атрибута data-model, 4 5 5c 5s и тд. Я думал создать объект со всеми моделями и цветами, и проверять уже с по нему, но что-то не знаю как это все организовать.

Comment: так и организуйте `var colors = { '5': ['red', 'white'], '5s' : ['green', 'yellow'], ...}`

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать через jQuery по мотивам вот этого [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=220O4N_BbLA). Прикрепить объект вида `{модель1: [цвет1, цвет2, цвет3]}`, а дальше практически так же как в примере.